# Django forms: how do I display the initial blank form?

Tags: python, django-forms

I have this view function:

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = SearchForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            lawyers = Lawyer.objects.all()
            [ other if statements ]
            ....
    else:
        form = SearchForm()
        return render_to_response('search.html', {'form': form})
```

I would think that when the page loads the `else` statement will be executed with the initial blank form. But this is not the case. To have the form displayed initially I have to add it inside the first `if`:

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = SearchForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            lawyers = Lawyer.objects.all()
            [ other if statements ]
            ....
        form = SearchForm()
        return render_to_response('search.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = SearchForm()
        return render_to_response('search.html', {'form': form})
```

Can you help why the first `if` is never false? Thank you.

The entire view function is [here](http://pastebin.com/m3b9f58bb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you post a form with `method=GET` you don't actually change the method from the initial request: it was `method=GET` too.

You can either use `method=POST` in your form, and your if statement will check for that, or you could check for the existence of the required fields, `first_name`, `last_name` or both, as your form requires.

```
if 'first_name' in request.GET or 'last_name' in request.GET:
    form = SearchForm(request.GET)
else:
    form = SearchForm()
```

You might want to abstract this into the form itself, modifying the `__init__` method, but you don't have to.

Answer (score 2):

Every normal HTTP request (like when you go to http://stackoverflow.com) is a GET request. It is generally a good idea to use POST as the method of your forms when they change some data.

You should read: [When do you use POST and when do you use GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585/when-do-you-use-post-and-when-do-you-use-get)